# What is the conventional way to divide a source file into several modules?

Tags: module, scope, racket

I've got a source file about 380 lines long. It's well past the point where it's hard to read because it's just a big sea of `define`s. I'd like to break it up, preferably into several scopes, not just by inserting a comment before each group of related definitions. I'd also prefer not to break it into separate source files, since I've got several source files that are all very similar: each is an experiment with a different way of doing the same thing. If I broke each one into multiple source files, I'd have a proliferation that I couldn't keep track of.

I figure that the [`module`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._module-syntax%29) and [`module*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._submodules%29) forms are made for this, but I haven't yet figured out how they're all meant to work together. I've tried various combinations, with varying levels of success, none fully satisfactory. I figured I'd just ask here how it's done.

The source file looks roughly like this:

```
#lang debug at-exp racket

(require rackunit data/collection racket/dict racket/generic racket/pretty
         racket/hash describe "graph.rkt")  ; <--- same requires needed in every scope
(provide make-slipnet run-slipnet spread-activation ...)

;; defines for making a 'slipnet' graph ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(define ...)
(define ...)
(module+ test
  ...)
(define ...)
(module+ test
  ...)
...
(define (make-slipnet ...) ...) ;The rest of the file only needs these
(define (run-slipnet ...) ...)  ;two functions from this section.

;; defines for doing spreading activation ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(define ...)
(define ...)
(module+ test
  ...)
...
(define (spread-activation ...) ...) ;The rest of the file only needs this
                                     ;function from this section
;; Etc.

(module+ main
  ;generate some human-readable output here, calling make-slipnet,
  ;run-slipnet, spread-activation, functions from "graph.rkt", etc.
)
```

How do you divide these functions up into their natural groups?

Comment: I just found something that might make this whole approach hopeless: when the various functions are in separate modules, they can't be accessed from the REPL in DrRacket. This means you can't experiment with those functions at the REPL. Or is there a convenient way to divide the source file into separate scopes and still access the "private" functions from the REPL?

Comment: Even after I've broken the file into a few modules, it still looks like a big sea of `define`s. If Racket provides some completely different way to make large source files readable, please let me know! (I think I remember reading somewhere that it's recommended to simply *not* make long source files.)

Answer (score 1):

Use submodules for semantic organization. Use comments for visual organization.

Submodules are useful when code should only be run in certain modes (eg `test` submodules for testing, `main` submodules for programs/commands, etc). They're also useful when you need the same helper function both at compile time (within a macro transformer) and at run time; you can define it once in a submodule and require the submodule at multiple phases.

But otherwise, just use comments and whitespace. My current preference is to separate major sections with lines of 60 equal signs (double line) and minor subsections with lines of 40 hyphens. Sometimes I put a section title below the line (if I can think of a concise label).

Tip: in both Emacs and DrRacket, you can insert 60 equal signs by hitting `Escape` `6` `0` `=`. Likewise for inserting *n* copies of any other character.

Example:

```
;; ============================================================
;; Data definitions

;; A Vertex is a Symbol.

;; A Graph is (graph (hashof Vertex (Listof Vertex))).
(struct graph (out-edges))

;; ============================================================
;; Graph algorithms

;; ----------------------------------------
;; Paths

;; find-path : Graph Vertex Vertex -> (U #f (Listof Vertex))
(define (find-path g from to) ....)

;; ----------------------------------------
;; Strongly-connected components (SCCs)

;; vertex->scc : Graph Vertex -> (Listof Vertex)
(define (vertex->scc g vertex) ....)

;; ============================================================
;; External forms

;; read-graph : InputPort -> Graph
(define (read-graph in) ....)

;; write-graph : Graph OutputPort -> Void
(define (write-graph g out) ....)
```

Comment: Ah, I think that's the crucial insight I needed: submodules for semantic organization, comments for visual organization. The example is great: it shows how many more comments you need than I've been using to conquer the "sea of defines". Thanks.